# DXF Plugin issue Geoserver 2.13.1 (HTTP Error: 503)

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to install the DXF plugin for Geoserver 2.13.1 which is running as a windows service but encounter the below error...

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /geoserver/. Reason:

Service Unavailable
```

I am only including the core jar file as I don't have WPS installed.

My workflow is copy the jar file to my WEB-INF/lib folder and restart the Geoserver service. Is there anything else additionally I should be doing?

Comment: please look in the log file and add the actual error message

Answer (score 0):

I clearly didn't give it enough time to process and restart, I waited for a little longer when trying to register it this time and it worked!